# Examples of implementetional composite pattern for graphic primitives

Tags: c++, design-patterns, composite

Can you tell me where I can see some examples (articles, opensource projects) of implementetional composite pattern on C++ (desirable full source code), on an example of problem: graphic primitives - rectangle, ellipse, arc and etc. This primitives may be to unite in one object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this one: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite/cpp/2